# How to filter list of items based on substring?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which has collection of filepaths and i want to extract the paths which only contains `'mp4'`.

```
lists = ['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', 'The mp4 version.vlc'
         '/Users/2. intro.vtt', '/Users/1. ppt.rar', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']
```

Expected output:

```
['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', 'The mp4 version.vlc','/Users/2. ppt.mp4']
```

I tried the below code but its not exactly giving me the correct output. My code looks:

```
lists = ['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4',
         '/Users/2. intro.vtt', '/Users/1. ppt.rar', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']


def Filter(string, substr):
    return [str for str in string if
            any(sub in str for sub in substr)]


searchString = 'mp4'
result = Filter(lists, searchString)
print(f'{result}')
```

If I run the program, it gives me the following output:

```
['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', '/Users/1. ppt.rar', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix?

Comment: you want file path where file has specific extension ? ie you want to create your function like that?

Comment: What's the point of that `any()`? Think about what you're doing here: You loop over all elements of `string`, and select the element if it contains _any of the elements of `substr`!_ Since `substr` is a string, the elements of `substr` are the individual characters, so you end up selecting the elements of `string` that contain _any of the characters in `substr`. To fix this, either remove the second loop, or pass a _list_ to `substr` if you want to support multiple substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
lists = ['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4',
         '/Users/2. intro.vtt', '/Users/1. ppt.rar', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']

def filterSubstr(lists, substr):
    return [x for x in lists if substr in x]

searchString = 'mp4'
print(filterSubstr(lists, searchString))
```

Result:

```
['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']
```

Comment: it works for the end condition. but if the substring is inside the string, its not working. some string looks like 'The mp4 version.vlc'

Comment: I edited it. It should return if the substring is found anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to check if `substr` is in each item in the list.

```
def Filter(string, substr):
    return [item for item in string if substr in item]
```

Your code, i.e.

```
any(sub in str for sub in substr)
```

checks if ANY of the letters 'm', 'p', or '4' are in `str`, since you have a nested comprehension that iterates through each character in `substr` itself.

I would also not use '`str`' as a variable name as you've done, since it's used for the built-in `str` class.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module which makes it easy to actually check the file's extension — which is a more rigorous test than  merely whether the one string is a substring of another:

```
from pathlib import Path


file_paths = ['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', '/Users/2. intro.vtt', '/Users/1. ppt.rar',
              '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']

def filter_on_extension(paths, ext):
    return [path for path in paths if Path(path).suffix == ext]

file_extension = '.mp4'
result = filter_on_extension(file_paths, file_extension)
print(result)  # -> ['/Users/me/1. intro.mp4', '/Users/2. ppt.mp4']
```